# Google hybrid OpenID+OAuth login not prompting for OAuth access

Tags: python, oauth, openid

I'm trying to implement Google's hybrid OpenID+OAuth login on a Google AppEngine site. For some reason, my login link only prompts the user to give login access via their Google account (OpenID). It does not ask for access to Contacts/Docs/etc (OAuth).

The example on Google's site uses this URL for login:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/openid2/auth?
openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&
openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&
openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&
openid.return_to=http://googlecodesamples.com/hybrid/index.php&
openid.realm=http://googlecodesamples.com&
openid.mode=checkid_setup&
openid.ns.ui=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0&
openid.ns.ext1=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0&
openid.ext1.mode=fetch_request&
openid.ext1.type.email=http://axschema.org/contact/email&
openid.ext1.type.first=http://axschema.org/namePerson/first&
openid.ext1.type.last=http://axschema.org/namePerson/last&
openid.ext1.type.country=http://axschema.org/contact/country/home&
openid.ext1.type.lang=http://axschema.org/pref/language&
openid.ext1.required=email,first,last,country,lang&
openid.ns.oauth=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0&
openid.oauth.consumer=googlecodesamples.com&
openid.oauth.scope=http://docs.google.com/feeds/+http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/+http://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people/
```

[Click here to visit link above](https://accounts.google.com/o/openid2/auth?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.return_to=http://googlecodesamples.com/hybrid/index.php&openid.realm=http://googlecodesamples.com&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns.ui=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0&openid.ns.ext1=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_request&openid.ext1.type.email=http://axschema.org/contact/email&openid.ext1.type.first=http://axschema.org/namePerson/first&openid.ext1.type.last=http://axschema.org/namePerson/last&openid.ext1.type.country=http://axschema.org/contact/country/home&openid.ext1.type.lang=http://axschema.org/pref/language&openid.ext1.required=email,first,last,country,lang&openid.ns.oauth=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0&openid.oauth.consumer=googlecodesamples.com&openid.oauth.scope=http://docs.google.com/feeds/+http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/+http://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people/)

If you click the link, note how it prompts for access to Email/Country/Language, in addition to Docs and Contacts.

If I replace these 3 parameters with my values:

```
openid.return_to=http://2.myapp.appspot.com&
openid.realm=http://*.myapp.appspot.com&
openid.oauth.consumer=myapp.appspot.com&
```

It still displays the login page, but only asks for Email/Country/Language...no mention of Docs/Contacts.

The app domain is registered and verified with Google - am I missing something? If I implement OAuth separately and generate an auth URL for Docs & Contacts, it works fine...but I would really like to do everything in one step with this hybrid approach, if possible.

Comment: Although this is _on_ App Engine, it isn't really _about_ App Engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a hybrid request to be considered valid, the oauth2 consumer and the OpenID2 realm must 'match'. In this case, the realm would match some value for consumer such as 2.myapp.appspot.com, but not myapp.appspot.com

One possible solution would be to also register '2.myapp.appspot.com' as your OAuth2 consumer.

Comment: Thanks! It occurred to me shortly after asking that the subdomain thing might be an issue. After registering the subdomain as an OAuth2 consumer, it works perfectly.